# Read NFC Chips using the ACR122U and Python 3

Tags: python, macos, nfc, rfid, scrypt

I would like to read NFC cards I own and print something according to the specific ID of the CHip. 
Let's say I have 3 cards of ID: 1,2,3. 
I would like to make a python script allowing me to print 'Card 1' for ID 1... and so on.

For now, I have tried using the NFCPY Github but can not manage to make it work.

Any help would be appreciated...
I am average in python and very new in the NFC field :)

Thanks a lot